# When I remove a window from service class then i am facing these errors and window taking too much time to show

Tags: android, service, window, broadcast

I need show a dailog when a outgoing call is detect and remove it when call is disconnect.

Please let me know the error and how can I resolve it.

Following is my code:

My BroadCast

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        action = intent.getAction();
        no = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);


        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            boolean block = CheckForBlock();
            if (!block) {

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, OutgoingService.class);
                intent1.putExtra("number", no);
                intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startService(intent1);
            }
            CheckAlert();
        } else if (action.equals(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)) {

            String phoneState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(phoneState)) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, OutgoingService.class);
                context.stopService(intent1);


            } else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(phoneState)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, phoneState + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
//        }


//        CheckForBlock();
//        CheckAlert();

    }
```

My Service class

```
public class OutgoingService extends Service {
    WindowManager windowManager;
    private View mView;
    String number;

    boolean Recording;
    boolean Controlling;

    GestureDetector detector;

    Cursor cr;
    ContentResolver resolver;

    private int number1, type, date, duration, name;
    String phone_Number, call_name, call_Type, call_Date;

    TextView UserNameTextView, statusText, UserStatusTextView, UserNumberTextView, UserTypeTextView, UserCallingNoteTextView, UserPredictionTextView;
    Switch Controlling_Switch;
    TextView RecordingText;
    Button End_Call;

    ImageView On_Speaker, Mute_Speaker, Dialpad;

    List<ControlingSettingBean> settingBeen;
    AudioManager audioManager;
    String Name;
    boolean name_empty = false;
    boolean ON_SPEAKER_MODE = false;
    boolean ON_MUTE_MODE = false;


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {

        if (intent != null) {
            number = intent.getStringExtra("number");
        }

        audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        mView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.alert_window, null);

//        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.layout_for__Animation);
//        linearLayout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alert_window));

        RecordingText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.RecordingText);
        statusText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.statusText);
        UserNameTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.UserNameTextView);
        UserStatusTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.UserStatusTextView);
        UserNumberTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.UserNumberTextView);
        UserTypeTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.UserTypeTextView);
        UserCallingNoteTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.UserCallingNoteTextView);
        UserPredictionTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.UserPredictionTextView);
        End_Call = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.End_Call);
        On_Speaker = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.On_Speaker);
        Mute_Speaker = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.Mute_Speaker);
        Dialpad = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.Dialpad);

        if (DashBoard.loggedIn) {

            windowManager.addView(mView, params);
        }


        Controlling_Switch = (Switch) mView.findViewById(R.id.Controlling_Switch);

        UserNumberTextView.setText(number);
        statusText.setText("Outgoing call");

        Name = getContactName(this, number);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Name) || Name.equalsIgnoreCase("unknown")) {
            name_empty = true;

        } else {

            UserNameTextView.setText(Name);
        }


        if (AppPreferences.getInstance(this).isRecordingOutgoingEnabled()) {
            Recording = true;
        } else {
            Recording = false;
        }


        if (Recording) {
            RecordingText.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alerter_pulse));
        }

        settingBeen = Database.getInstance(this).GetAlertSettings();

        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(settingBeen.get(0).getAllAlert())) {
            Controlling = true;
        } else {

            Controlling = false;
        }


        Controlling_Switch.setChecked(Controlling);

        CheckForCallingNote(number);
        checkLastCallLog();
        if (checkConnection()) {
            GetNameFromServer();
        } else {
            if (name_empty) {
                UserNameTextView.setText("UNKNOWN");
            }
        }


        On_Speaker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (ON_SPEAKER_MODE) {
                    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
                    ON_SPEAKER_MODE = false;
                    On_Speaker.setImageResource(R.drawable.speaker_off);
                } else {
                    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                    ON_SPEAKER_MODE = true;
                    On_Speaker.setImageResource(R.drawable.speaker_on);
                }
            }
        });

        Mute_Speaker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (ON_MUTE_MODE) {
                    ON_MUTE_MODE = false;
                    audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
                    Mute_Speaker.setImageResource(R.drawable.mice_off);
                } else {
                    ON_MUTE_MODE = true;
                    audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);
                    Mute_Speaker.setImageResource(R.drawable.mice_on);
                }

            }
        });

        End_Call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // End Call

                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Method method = null;
                        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) OutgoingService.this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                        Class clazz = null;
                        try {
                            clazz = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
                            method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                            method.setAccessible(true);
                            ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager);
                            telephonyService.endCall();
                            windowManager.removeView(mView);
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, 1000);


            }
        });


        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void GetNameFromServer() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(this.getPackageName() + "pre", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (preferences.getBoolean("pre", true)) {
            if (checkConnection()) {
                SharedPreferences preferences1 = this.getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", MODE_PRIVATE);
                AndroidNetworking.post(GET_PREDECTION_NAME_STATUS)
                        .addHeaders("Authorization", preferences1.getString("Api_Key", ""))
                        .addBodyParameter("mobile", number)
                        .build()
                        .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                                    if (!jsonObject.getBoolean("error")) {
                                        if (name_empty) {
                                            UserNameTextView.setText(jsonObject.getString("contact_name"));
                                        }
                                        UserTypeTextView.setText("Type : " + jsonObject.getString("type"));
                                        UserStatusTextView.setText("Status : \n" + jsonObject.getString("status"));
                                    }

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(ANError anError) {

                            }
                        });

            }
        }
    }

    private void checkLastCallLog() {
        List<StatsBean> been = new ArrayList<>();

        String string = CallLog.Calls.DATE;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


        }
        resolver = this.getContentResolver();
        cr = resolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, string);

        number1 = cr.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        type = cr.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        date = cr.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        duration = cr.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        name = cr.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);

        while (cr.moveToNext()) {

            phone_Number = cr.getString(number1);
            call_name = cr.getString(name);
            call_Type = cr.getString(type);
            call_Date = cr.getString(date);

            long seconds = Long.parseLong(call_Date);
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            SimpleDateFormat simpleTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            String datte = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date(seconds));
            String ttime = simpleTimeFormat.format(new Date(seconds));
            String call_Duration = cr.getString(duration);
            int callcode = Integer.parseInt(call_Type);


            switch (callcode) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    call_Type = "Outgoing";

                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    call_Type = "Incoming";

                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    call_Type = "Missed";


                    break;
            }


            if (call_Type.equalsIgnoreCase("Outgoing")) {

                phone_Number = phone_Number.replace(" ", "");
                if (phone_Number.length() > 10) {

                    int l = phone_Number.length();
                    int finallength = 10 - l;
                    String finalno = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < finallength; i++) {
                        finalno = finalno + "0";
                    }
                    phone_Number = finalno + (phone_Number);
                }


                if (phone_Number.equalsIgnoreCase(number)) {
                    StatsBean statsBean = new StatsBean();
                    statsBean.setNUMBER(phone_Number.trim());
                    statsBean.setDURATION(call_Duration);
                    statsBean.setDATE(datte);
                    statsBean.setTIME(ttime);
                    statsBean.setTYPE(call_Type);
                    been.add(statsBean);
                }


            }
        }


        Collections.sort(been, new Comparator<StatsBean>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(StatsBean statsBean, StatsBean t1) {
                return statsBean.getDATE().compareTo(t1.getDATE());
            }
        });

        if (!been.isEmpty()) {

            if (been.size() > 0) {
                UserPredictionTextView.setText(number + "\nlast call was " + been.get(been.size() - 1).getDATE() + ", " + been.get(been.size() - 1).getDURATION() + " seconds");
            } else if (been.size() == 0) {
                UserPredictionTextView.setText(number + "\nlast call was " + been.get(0).getDATE() + ", " + been.get(0).getDURATION() + " seconds");
            } else if (been.isEmpty()) {
                UserPredictionTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else {
            UserPredictionTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


    }

    private void CheckPrediction(String number) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(this.getPackageName() + "pre", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (preferences.getBoolean("pre", true)) {
            if (checkConnection()) {
                SharedPreferences preferences1 = this.getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", MODE_PRIVATE);
                AndroidNetworking.post(GET_PREDECTION)
                        .addHeaders("Authorization", preferences1.getString("Api_Key", ""))
                        .addBodyParameter("mobile", number)
                        .build()
                        .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                                    if (!jsonObject.getBoolean("error")) {

                                        if (jsonObject.getString("is_user_registered").equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {

                                            JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("outgoing");
                                            int outAv = Integer.parseInt(jsonArray1.getJSONObject(0).getString("average"));
                                            if (outAv > 60 * 5) {
                                                outAv = Integer.parseInt(jsonArray1.getJSONObject(0).getString("average")) / 60;
                                                UserPredictionTextView.setText("Call should be " + (outAv - 5) + " seconds to " + (outAv + 5) + " seconds");
                                            } else {

                                                UserPredictionTextView.setText("Call should be " + (outAv - 5) + " seconds to " + (outAv + 5) + " seconds");
                                            }

                                        }


                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(ANError anError) {

                            }
                        });
            } else {
                UserPredictionTextView.setText("Check your internet connection");
            }
        }

    }

    private void CheckForCallingNote(String number) {
        List<CallingCard> callingCards = null;
        callingCards = Database.getInstance(this).GetAllCard();

        if (!callingCards.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < callingCards.size(); i++) {
                String number1 = callingCards.get(i).getNUMBER();
                number1 = number1.substring(number1.length() - 10);
                if (number1.equalsIgnoreCase(number.substring(number.length() - 10))) {

                    UserCallingNoteTextView.setText("Note :\n" + callingCards.get(i).getTEXT());

                } else {
                    if (i == callingCards.size() - 1) {
                        UserCallingNoteTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }


        } else {
            UserCallingNoteTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    public static String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String contactName = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }

        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }

        return contactName;
    }


    private boolean checkConnection() {
        boolean isConnected = ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected();
        return isConnected;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        if (!isMyServiceRunning(OutgoingService.class) && windowManager != null) {

            windowManager.removeView(mView);
        }


    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And error -

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: bindalinfotech.callteria, PID: 14564
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service bindalinfotech.callteria.Activites.Services.OutgoingService@2bc53ed7: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=android.widget.LinearLayout{3ac0efda V.E..... .......D 0,0-540,960} not attached to window manager
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:4032)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:211)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=android.widget.LinearLayout{3ac0efda V.E..... .......D 0,0-540,960} not attached to window manager
                                                                              at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:412)
                                                                              at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:338)
                                                                              at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:117)
                                                                              at bindalinfotech.callteria.Activites.Services.OutgoingService.onDestroy(OutgoingService.java:528)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:4013)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:211) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```